# NSURLRequest POST to google app engine?

Tags: iphone, python, google-app-engine, http-post

I am currently looking into GAE (Python) and I'm trying to send POST requests from an iPhone application.

Sending with GET method works fine, but it just fails when I use POST method.

Here's the server side:

```
class echoHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        password = self.request.get("password")
        if password == "ping":
            self.response.out.write("pong")
        else:
            self.response.out.write("erreur de password")

    def post(self):
        password = self.request.get("password")
        if password == "ping":
            self.response.out.write("pong")
        else:
            self.response.out.write("erreur de password")
```

and on the client side:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myapp.appspot.com/echo"]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *maRequete = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [maRequete setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *essaiMdp = @"password=ping";
    [maRequete setHTTPBody:[essaiMdp dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //[maRequete setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[essaiMdp length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    //[maRequete setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    //[maRequete setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

    NSURLResponse *reponse;
    NSError *erreur;

    NSData *donneesPOST = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:maRequete returningResponse:&reponse error:&erreur];

    if (donneesPOST) {
        NSString *strResultat = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:donneesPOST encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"reponse recue !");
        NSLog(strResultat);
        resultat.text = strResultat;

    }
    else {
        if (erreur) {
            NSLog(@"erreur lors de la requete HTTP:%@", url);
            NSLog(@"erreur: %@", [erreur localizedDescription]);

        }
    }
```

What's weird is that everything works in localhost, but when I deploy the app on the internet, POST method stopped working.

Any idea ? Thx !

Comment: 'Stopped working' how? What do you see on the client side? In the logs on the server? Have you added debugging code to the server to determine what's actually getting sent?

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, I was saying that the POST method doesn't seem to be called (server side) when this app is deployed on the internet (Google App Engine). About the debugging code, locally the Google App Engine SDK can help you debug that, but when you deploy it I don't know if I'm still able to do that. I've been trying to manually send http requests using Telnet and what I get was a 400 error (malformed url), although it was working locally...

Comment: I'm seeing this issue as well. I've got an even simpler sandbox setup and POST requests fail. Did you ever get this resolved? So far I haven't gotten it working yet.

Comment: I have this same problem now as well!  Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a possibility that your server is set up to redirect requests that don't end in a slash to one that does? In other words, maybe `http://myapp.appspot.com/echo` is redirecting to `http://myapp.appspot.com/echo/`, and a redirect is always a GET.

Comment: I think your werservice perosn use get method instead of request method

Comment: The server-side application works fine locally but POST method won't get called when its deployed on GAE. I guess you're right, it look like it's redirect-related :/. I'll try adding the Host header to the http request (it works with Telnet)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending a POST request to Google App Engine, change the URL to 'https' "http://myapp.appspot.com/echo" to "https://myapp.appspot.com/echo".

From what i have experienced, sending a "non-https" url to Google App Engine causes a redirect.